# Qt: Adding a special item to QMenu

Tags: qt, menu, qmenu

Some programs like Maya and Wings3D have a menu, which includes a special link on some menu items on the right side (usually a square) that triggers a different feature.  For example, Wings3D might have an item called "Cube", which makes a standard cube.  However, if you click on the highlightable/selectable box beside the "Cube" item, it will perform a different operation.  I attached an image of the Wings3D example.

Is this an easy way to do this using QMenu and QAction?  Should I create a special layout for the QMenu or do I need to subclass it to get more fine-grained control?

[image]

Comment: I would love to see a solution to this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [QWidgetAction](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidgetaction.html) to accomplish this. But it might take a bit of work to ensure that those actions stay consistent in terms of the look & feel with the typical rendering of QActions across different platforms and styles.